# YA book about teenagers kidnapped and put to work building a space station?

Tags: story-identification

I read a book sometime in the late 90s about a teenaged boy and girl who are kidnapped from Earth and put to work building a space station as slaves with a bunch of other children.  I only remember a few details--all the children wore color-coded smocks, and the kidnapped boy had a rich relative who got them all freed eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this one out: [Away Is a Strange Place to Be, by H. M. Hoover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0525445056).

> On Earth in the year 2349, orphaned Abby Tabor helps her uncle run a luxury inn, which she will one day inherit. Guests like spoiled, obnoxious Bryan Bishop, however, convince the girl that she's not cut out to be an innkeeper. Suddenly Abby and Bryan are kidnapped; with hundreds of other children, they're told their families have arranged this "legal" abduction to VitaCon, a new space habitat. When Abby learns they might all be disposed of when they reach maturity, she's determined to escape. But can she trust Bryan, or will his personality flaws kill them both?